# Django class based generic views: cannot import name TemplateView

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Django fires exception `cannot import name TemplateView` how to fix this?

**view.py** :

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class Monitor(TemplateView):
    template_name  = 'helo.html'
```

---

**urls.py** :

```
from monitor.views import Monitor

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', Monitor.as_view()),
)
```

Comment: You'll need to post more source code than that to get a diagnosis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what Django version you are using, but only in Django 1.3 a class called TemplateView exists. Its import should be:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
```

Comment: What are possible alternatives on 1.2.3 for this?

Comment: This is a new feature called class-based generic view. Prior to 1.3 generic views were implemented as functions. The function-based implementation has been deprecated in favor of the class-based generic view. For more help consult this documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/